# "invalid date" al utilizar moment.js con una fecha del año pasado

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

Utilizo una funcion en javaScript para obtener la fecha del calendario de mi pagina y convertirlo en utc.

Ejemplo 1:

```
function getStartDate(){

    var utcToConvertStartDate = $('#startDate').val(); //01-02-2019 10:00
    var starDateConvert = moment(utcToConvertStartDate).utc().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
    console.log("starDateConvert: " + starDateConvert); //01-02-2019 16:00

    return starDateConvert;
}
```

Ejemplo 2:

```
function getStartDate(){

    var utcToConvertStartDate = $('#startDate').val(); //01-01-2019 10:00
    var starDateConvert = moment(utcToConvertStartDate).utc().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
    console.log("starDateConvert: " + starDateConvert); //Invalid date

    return starDateConvert;
}
```

Al seleccionar la fecha del 1 de febrero en adelante no tengo ningún problema, me hace la función correctamente y me convierte el horario en utc pero, al seleccionar la fecha 1 de Enero hacia atrás me pinta en la consola del navegador "Invalid date".

Comment: quité la etiqueta de `java` pues no veo en tu problema donde se ocupe

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que he leido en esta pregunta similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43848300/moment-format-returns-invalid-date , puede que pasandole el formato de String de salida esperado se solucione tu problema:

```
   var utcToConvertStartDate = $('#startDate').val(); //01-01-2019 10:00
    var starDateConvert = moment(utcToConvertStartDate,'DD-MM-YYYY').utc().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
    console.log("starDateConvert: " + starDateConvert); //Invalid date

    return starDateConvert;
```

Answer (score 0):

Pude solucionar el problema. En mi función retorné e hice la conversión directamente sobre la fecha obtenida, aunque se me hace raro porque veo que se hace casi lo mismo.

```
return moment($("#startDate").val(), "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm").utc().format("DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm");
```